# LinqtoExcel: Not able to send value from excel

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-excel

First of all below is my Excel file.

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| Data            | Output                      |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| URL             | http://www.gmail.com        |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| Username        | abc123                      |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| Password        | 123abc                      |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
```

In my Initialize class I am calling URL to be navigates.

Then in test class to get data from excel for Username and Password. Below is my code.

My Main class contains

```
PageObject credLogin = new PageObject();
var fileName = @"path";
string sheetName = "Sheet";
var book = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(fileName);
var users = from x in book.Worksheet<Login>(sheetName)select x;
foreach (var x in users)
{
    My.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(a["URL"]);
    credLogin.Login(x["uid"], x["pwd"]);
}
```

--> My PageObject class contains

```
namespace Abc13465
{
    class PageObject
    {

     //use using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
     [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "txtuname")]
       public IWebElement Username { get; set; }
     [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "txtpass")]
     public IWebElement Password { get; set; }
     [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "login_button")]
     public IWebElement logbtn { get; set; }

     public void Login(string uname, string paswd)
     {

         Username.EnterText(uid);
         Password.EnterText(pwd);
         logbtn.Click();
     }
```

PN: URL link and Username/Password are changed to but al functions are same.

My Question:

What am I missing here? Neither, I am not able to get data from excel for username and password. Nor able to navigate to the site

Comment: What is Mydriver and does it work for any hard coded url you enter?

Comment: @RetroCoder it is `My.driver`. And yes it works with any URL you enter.

Comment: You provided to much code, try to use debugger to locate the exact place where is the error. Btw, I think you may have trouble with linq delayed execution when you are doing 
var users = from x in book.Worksheet<Login>(sheetName)select x; and then
foreach (var x in users). Before using foreach, you need to cast user to array or list or whatever you like.

Comment: @AlexButenko can you explain little more please?

Comment: @user120 Explain what? Linq - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx, debugger - depends on IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Format that you are using is not correct. I made that same mistake so it was not working. Use below format and It should work.

```
+----------------------+----------+------------------+
|          URL         | Username |      Password    |
+----------------------+----------+------------------+
| http://www.gmail.com | abc123   |      123abc      |
+----------------------+----------+------------------+
```